# Google Play Store Internal Test Apk isn't immediately available

Tags: android, google-play-console

Hello I have published an app on the internal test track and from what I was reading it should be immediately available to all testers (if it don't is the first upload).
But always if I upload a new version to my test track it seems to go through the standard verification process and that is taking currently forever because of corona. So my question is why aren't my Apk/bundles that I publish to the internal test track immediately available to my testers?
Even after I have received the message that my update is online, I can only see the first Alpha Track release I have uploaded and no update to the newly released update. The version code of the update is greater than the version code of the first uploaded alpha release.

Comment: Every release goes through verification process.

Comment: But in their documentation they say that if you want to directly deliver test updates to test users you should use the internal test track.  And why am I unable to update through the play store once the update is online? Only the first uploaded alpha release is available, none of the updates I have uploaded.

Comment: Okay I was able to update after forcing the play store app to stop but still it shouldn't be normal that it takes so long before my internal testers are getting updates. Why should I use the internal test track if it is the same like a closed alpha track? I thought the whole benefit of an internal test track is that you can deliver fast fixes to testers so that they don't have to wait for the updates like in an alpha or beta release.

Comment: Good point Martin, but how did you manage to force it? Did you mean force-close Play Store?

Comment: Yes that's I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Maybe it were a good idea if Google would show a note or something when you upload a Release to an internal test track that even if it shows that the release is in verification process, it is already available to testers. Very confusing everything